# Cannot Find dynamic asp:Control inside a Gridview using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, aspxgridview

In an ASP.Net Application I have an aspx file inside which I have an Update Panel with a Gridview Inside it. Inside the Gridview there is a table which also contains some panels. There are some controls inside those panels.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Gridview ID="GridView1" runat = "server"...>
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <table>
         <asp:Panel ID="pnlVisualAst" runat="server" Visible="false">
              <tr>
                <td style="text-indent: 50px; width: 25%">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblVisAst" runat="server" Text="Visual Assitance"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <asp:Button ID="btnVisAst" class="button"  runat="server" Text="View"/>
                  <asp:Image ID="popImg" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Eval("VA_Img"))%>' runat="server" Visible="false" />
                </td>
              </tr>
        </asp:Panel>
     </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField >
 </Columns>
</asp:Gridview>
```

Now, I am writing a JQuery function to capture the click event for the button inside the Gridview and show the image field in a pop up window.

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ready', function ()
    {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function ()
        {
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find($('#<%= btnVisAst.ClientID %>')).click(function ()
            {
                $('#<%=popImg.ClientID%>').dialog
                  ({
                      title: "my jquery popup",
                      width: 430,
                      height: 200,
                      modal: true,
                      button:
                          {
                              Close:
                              function ()
                              {
                                  $(this).dialog('Close');
                              }
                          }
                  });
                $(this).prop('checked', true);

            });
        });

    });
```

The Problem with the above code is it cannot find the the dynamic controls inside that Gridview. It shows the 'btnVisAst' and 'popImg' does not exist in the current context.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: It is always complicated to work with control ID in GridView items. Since there is one `btnVisAst` in each item, and since each ID must be unique in the HTML output, ASP.NET adds some prefix to make each one different. To eliminate this problem, you can set the `CssClass` of the controls in the ItemTemplate and use that class name in your jQuery selector instead of the ID.

Comment: I have already tried it. if I use CSS class instead of ID it generates events for all the button at the same time  no specification. I don't want that to happen that id why I was taking this approach.

Comment: And, using the ID, which item were you targetting with your jQuery selector?

Comment: I am targetting the button and if it is clicked i am targetting the img control as I ahhev bind database table column inside it

Comment: Add `OnClientClick="return myFoo(this)"` to your button.

Comment: Aaron Cuffman's answer probably solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ConnorsFan. Use classes instead. If you apply a class to your visit button, say "classVisAst", then you could do something like this:

```
$('.classVisAst').click(function ()
        {
            var newDialog = $(this).siblings("img").dialog
              ({
                  title: "my jquery popup",
                  width: 430,
                  height: 200,
                  modal: true,
                  button:
                      {
                          Close:
                          function ()
                          {
                              $(this).dialog('Close');
                          }
                      }
              });
            $(newDialog).dialog('open');

            $(this).prop('checked', true);

        });
```

Then you're not worrying about IDs at all because everything is relative.

Comment: But If I use class instead of ID's the button event fires for all the controls. Suppose if we have 4 buttons inside the Gridview and if i click 1 button it will show 4 pictures cause there are 4 buttons and for each button there are 4 pictures.

Comment: Are you using a class for the image as well? You shouldn't need to change the image at all. In my example I'm using the siblings function rather than applying a class to the image. In your initial code is seems like there is one image with each button. Is this not the case?

Comment: How can I find a dynamic asp:Image  control from clicking the button from this. The image itself a dynamic asp:Image control which is changing with every gridview table row.

Comment: @JabedHossain - He uses the `siblings` selector to find the image in the same item as the button.

Comment: If I do an alert inside the his function before the dialogue opens up it pops up an alertbox which is expected but the button doesnt show any image.

Comment: Your code wasn't actually trying to show the image it seems either. It's only readying the dialog. You also have to open it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It doesn't show any pop up window.

Comment: It doesn't show any pop up window. If I put alert inside the button click it work but it doesn't work with the image dialogue pop up

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching button assign a function to it.

```
<asp:Gridview ID="GridView1" runat = "server"...>
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
   <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Panel ID="pnlVisualAst" runat="server" Visible="false">
     <table><%--put table inside panel else you will have empty table element --%>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-indent: 50px; width: 25%">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblVisAst" runat="server" Text="Visual Assitance"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <asp:Button ID="btnVisAst" OnClientClick="return doSomething(this)" class="button"  runat="server" Text="View"/>
                  <asp:Image ID="popImg" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Eval("VA_Img"))%>' runat="server" Visible="false" />
                </td>
              </tr>
     </table>
        </asp:Panel>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField >
 </Columns>
</asp:Gridview>
```

javascript:

```
function doSomething(elem){//elem == input[type=submit]
    $('#'+ elem.id.replace('btnVisAst','popImg')).dialog
      ({
          title: "my jquery popup",
          width: 430,
          height: 200,
          modal: true,
          button:
              {
                  Close:
                  function ()
                  {
                      $(this).dialog('Close');
                  }
              }
      });
    $(elem).prop('checked', true);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good observation: the Panel cannot be inserted between the table and the rows.

Comment: If I add the javascript potion of the code it shows a javascript runtime error - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Comment: In your original code find the button and the image of interest and hardcode their id's from the page. THIS IS FOR TEST PURPOSE. Make sure it work.

Comment: I think the dialog thing is not working in this javascript code

Comment: The dialog is assigned to an img in your code. Little chance it will work. As well checked prop is set to button. Look at YOUR code. I show how to access the function and find sibling element. All others are yours. I hope my  code is useful.